# PHP script fails to get correct home page

Tags: php, function, server, root

This script is a function to define site url to send it to the big script but because it is shared hosting it gets incorrect path how can tell it the correct site path ? I wanna tell it the site url and script dir directly the script thinks this is the path `/hermes/bosnaweb23a/index.php` but the correct path is `/index.php` only. 
I wanna remove `/hermes/bosnaweb23a/`
because `/hermes/bosnaweb23a/` is the shared hosting path

```
<?php 

    function home_base_url(){
        $base_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) &&
        $_SERVER['HTTPS']!='off') ? 'https://' : 'http://';
        $tmpURL = dirname(__FILE__);
        $tmpURL = str_replace(chr(92),'/',$tmpURL);
        $tmpURL = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$tmpURL);
        $tmpURL = ltrim($tmpURL,'/');
        $tmpURL = rtrim($tmpURL, '/');

        if (strpos($tmpURL,'/')){
            $tmpURL = explode('/',$tmpURL);
            $tmpURL1 = $tmpURL[0];
            $tmpURL2 = $tmpURL[1];
            $tmpURL = $tmpURL1;
            if(!empty($tmpURL2)) $tmpURL .= '/'.$tmpURL2;
        }

        if ($tmpURL !== $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
            $base_url .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.$tmpURL.'/';
        else
            $base_url .= $tmpURL.'/';

        $base_url = str_replace('//','/',$base_url);
        $base_url = str_replace('http:/','http://',$base_url);
        $base_url = str_replace('https:/','https://',$base_url);

        return str_replace(dirname(__FILE__),'',$base_url); 
    }

    $local_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/';
    $sSoftware = strtolower( $_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] );


    function getSlashes() {
        $sSoftware = strtolower( $_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] );
        if ( strpos($sSoftware, "microsoft-iis") !== false ) return "\\";
        else return "/";
    }

    if ( strpos($sSoftware, "microsoft-iis") !== false ) {
        $local_path = str_replace(getSlashes(), '/', dirname(__FILE__)).'/';
    }
    function get_domain() {     
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    }



    $remote_path = home_base_url();

    if((strpos($remote_path, '127.0.0.1') !== false) || (strpos($remote_path, 'localhost') !== false)) {
        $find = str_replace(' ','',":\ ");
        @$local_path = end(explode($find,$local_path));
        define('DOCUMENT_ROOT', '/'.$local_path);
    }else{
        define('DOCUMENT_ROOT', '/'.$local_path);
    }

?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? trying to get canonical url ?

Comment: Please point out the actual and expected result and which part of the code is supposed to achieve the result and where you suspect the mistake.

Comment: Please define "correct" and "incorrect" in this case. Explain the rules you are trying to implement. Give a worked example. Explain what debugging you've done to try and narrow down the problem (because there's a lot of fiddly code here to work through) and roughly where you think it might be going wrong (and if you haven't debugged it all yet, please do so first). Currently your description of the problem is too vague. Remember we know **nothing** about your code except what you write here. Thanks.

Comment: i wanna tell it the site url and script dir directly the script thinks this is the path /hermes/bosnaweb23a/index.php but the correct path is /index.php only i wanna remove /hermes/bosnaweb23a/ because /hermes/bosnaweb23a/ is the shred hosting path

Comment: The script is root.php for Sendroid bulk sms script but it fails to get my site correct path :(

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` defines the path on disk. This is useless if you want to create a URL, because a URL is usually not mapped to a disk location directly. `$base_url.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/index.php";` should be all you need to construct the URL I think. Or if you don't want to specify "/index.php" hard-coded, then replace with `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` (assuming you want the name of the currently executing script). See also https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php for other variables which might be of use. I think you may have overcomplicated this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get `index.php` from `/hermes/bosnaweb23a/index.php` by using this code.

```
$url = explode("/", "/hermes/bosnaweb23a/index.php");
$script_name = end($url);
```

`$script_name` would be `index.php`.